# php parse array values

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I'm not very good when it comes to arrays so here's probably something very simple but not for me! I'm getting an array of values via POST and I need to parse them and store the values in a table. How should I use the classic parsing such as:

```
foreach($array as $a) {
  $text = $a->text;
  $name = $a->user->name;
}
```

etc to parse an array looking like this:

```
[item] => Array
        (
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bluetooth
                    [1] => WiFi
                    [2] => USB
                )

        )

This is the entire POST array:

Array
(
    [prodid] => 
    [Submit] => Save
    [productcode] => 797987
    [cat_id] => 66
    [brand] => Fysiomed
    [name] =>  asdc asdc asd c
    [productnew] => yes
    [item] => Array
        (
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Bluetooth
                    [1] => WiFi
                    [2] => USB
                )

        )

    [size] => 1
    [barcode] => 7979871
    [price] => 233.00
    [priceoffer] => 0.00
    [stock] => 50
    [weight] => 0.30
    [orderby] => 1
)
```

Comment: Could you tell us what are your POST inputs?

Comment: How does your POST array look like?

Comment: POST array added to 1st post.

Comment: It's not clear wht you want to do. You can't put a multi-dimensional array into a 2 dimensional table. You need to expand a bit.

Comment: I need to get all the tags as strings and add them to a table in my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( isset($_POST['item']) && isset($_POST['item']['tags']) ){
  foreach($_POST['item']['tags'] as $tag){
    //do stuff...e.g.
    echo $tag;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to get the text out? try this.

```
foreach($array['item']['tags'] as $tag) {
   $text = $tag;
}
```

Comment: This outputs the following Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: 'tag' should be 'tags', I think.

Comment: You have to replace array with whatever your array is called. $_POST maybe.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'item') {
      echo $value[$key]['tag'][0]. '<br>';
      echo $value[$key]['tag'][1]. '<br>';
      echo $value[$key]['tag'][2]. '<br>';
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to iterate through teh whole $_POST array

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your array is shaped like this, check this

```
$array = array( "item" => array( "tags" => array("Bluetooth", "Wifi", "USB" ) ) );
var_dump($array);
```

You will see something like this

```
array(1) {
  ["item"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tags"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Bluetooth"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Wifi"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "USB"
    }
  }
}
```

Now for parsing this array,

```
foreach($array as $in => $val) {
    // as $array has key=>value pairs, only one key value pair
    // here $in will have the key and $val will have the value
    // $in will be "item"
    print $in; // this will print "item"
    foreach($val as $in2 => $val2 ){
        // only one key : "tags"
        print $in; // this will print "tags"
        print $val2[0];  // this will print "Bluetooth"
        print $val2[1];  // this will print "Wifi"
    } 
}
```

I hope this clears you doubt regarding arrays.

Comment: I will use this as an example to try and understand them more. Thank you.